# Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.SpellCheck NuGet not working with Bing Search API (unauthorized)

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-cognitive-services, bing-api

I'm using .net-core3.1 with Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.SpellCheck NuGet package. I've read through entire documentation around Bing/cognitive API but I still find it very confusing as there are multiple APIs doing the same thing.

I got the API key from Microsoft.BingSearch on portal.azure.com and I'm using the free subscription. My subscription should however be valid as I am already using their LUIS without problems. Azure links to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bing/search-apis/bing-spell-check/quickstarts/rest/python for quick start but this does not work for me ("https://api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/SpellCheck" url gives me "NotFound" using the code below with my key).

code sample:

```cs
var x = new SpellCheckClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials("<API_KEY>"));
// endpoints I tried:
// x.Endpoint = "https://westeurope.api.bing.microsoft.com/v7.0/spellcheck";
// x.Endpoint = "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com/bing/v7.0";
// x.Endpoint = "https://api.bing.microsoft.com"; -- Not found
// x.Endpoint = "https://cognitiveservices.azure.com"; -- The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.
var y = await x.SpellCheckerWithHttpMessagesAsync("gona");
```

Using default endpoint gives me Unauthorized error code.

Anyone has any idea on how to use this API?

Answer (score 0):

You are right, the endpoint seems to be wrong. As you can see in the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cognitiveservices.language.spellcheck.spellcheckclient.endpoint?view=azure-dotnet&WT.mc_id=AI-MVP-5003365#Microsoft_Azure_CognitiveServices_Language_SpellCheck_SpellCheckClient_Endpoint), regarding this value:

> Supported Cognitive Services endpoints (protocol and hostname, for
> example: "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com",
> "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com").

So if you are using West Europe, it should be "https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com"

You can also check your API key by directly testing the console here: https://westeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/5f7d486e04d2430193e1ca8f760cd7ed/operations/57855119bca1df1c647bc358

- Choose your resource region (the one selected during key creation on Azure portal)
- Set your key value in "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" field
- Edit the "text" value in the query parameters
- Run the request

Comment: Thanks for your response. It looks like even with that endpoint I am getting 401 "Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource".

Tried with key from "Bing search v7" and from "Azure Cognitive Search". Really just odd how nothing seems to work and how there are so many endpoints thrown around.